# A touch interaction BUG of native view (like TextView \ PDFView) which nested in a AndroidView and scaled by a wrapped Box

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, scale, android-touch-event

**Describe the bug**

**Background**: I want use Android native view like PDFView in Android Compose, so I should use a  AndroidView to wrap it. And also I want my parent compose component set a scale factor by Modifier.scale().

Here is my code :

```kotlin
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Yellow),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(250F.dp, 80F.dp)
                    .scale(1.5F)
                    .background(Color.Gray),
            ) {
                AndroidView(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    factory = {
                        val pdfView = generatePDFView()
                        pdfView
                    }) {
                }
            }
        }
```

After that, I found the touch area of PDFView is not match the display area after scaling, but the touch area of compose component is right.

So, I guess that the scale modifier of Android Compose just handle the display effect of Android native view but does not handle its touch interaction properly

**Affected platforms**
Select one of the platforms below:

- Android
- Other

**Versions**

- Jetpack Compose version: Using composeBom, it version is : platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
- Android Studio Build: Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1
- Kotlin version: 1.7.20
- JDK (for desktop issues): 11

**To Reproduce**
Steps and/or the code snippet to reproduce the behavior, let's reproduce by a TextView:

1. Create a very simple Activity and setContent { // Compose content } in onCreate method
2. The compose content also very simple ,  Box -> Box -> AndroidView -> TextView
3. Scale the second Box to 1.5F and the set the text attribute of TextView with a long long string
4. TextView which nested in the scaled Box, has a complete wrong touch area！Only some left top area can click or scroll

```kotlin
class DemoScaleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG = "DemoScaleActivity"

    private var scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeStandardDoubleBox()
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ComposeStandardDoubleBox() {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Yellow),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(250F.dp, 80F.dp)
                    .scale(1.5F)
                    .background(Color.Gray),
            ) {
                AndroidView(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    factory = {
                        val pdfView = generatePDFView()
                        pdfView
                    }) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun generateTextView(): TextView {
        val textView = TextView(this).apply {
            movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance()
            //必须，垂直滚动，与布局中的scrollbars="vertical"等价
            isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = true;
            // 非必须，滚动条的位置样式
            scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY;
            // 非必须，滚动条的隐藏时长
            scrollBarFadeDuration = 1000;
            // 非必须
            isSingleLine = false;
            // 非必须，是否允许滚动条隐藏
            isVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled = true;
            // 必须
            movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance();

            setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.RED)
            text = generateTextString()
            setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("zzz", " !!!!! ")
            }
        }
        return textView
    }

    private fun generateTextString(): String {
        val aStr = "a".repeat(20)
        val bStr = "b".repeat(20)
        val cStr = "c".repeat(20)
        val dStr = "d".repeat(20)
        val result = StringBuilder()
        repeat(40) {
            result
                .append(aStr).append("\n")
                .append(bStr).append("\n")
                .append(cStr).append("\n")
                .append(dStr).append("\n")
        }
        return result.toString()
    }

}
```

**Screenshots**

**The correct touch interaction area without Scale modifier：**
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3962054/232718577-24fa0aec-6061-449a-80b8-d34b1c2d7b01.png

**The wrong touch interaction area with Scale modifier：**
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/3962054/232718306-f38facda-b08b-469f-9806-01a38302570f.png

I hope the TextView / PDFView has a correct touch interaction area after scaling the Box